# creating gallery- thumbnails on left, main image on right- not aligned on top despite floats & clear:both

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErVS5/)

I'm creating an image gallery that, ideally, should have a column of thumbnails on the left with a larger image on the right with both sections aligned along the top vertical axis.
To do this, I've floated the thumbnails and larger image left and right, respectively, and tried every combination of `clear:both` and `overflow:hidden` I could think of to achieve the top alignment to no avail. Any ideas?

I've included a JSFiddle at the top and an image below to give an idea of what I'm going for.

[image: ideal]

Comment: The jsfiddle is A LOT of code. Would you mind posting just the code and CSS for the gallery display ?

Comment: @CosminAtanasiu Sorry about that, just trying to provide any bit of info that may help. The link in my original post has been updated per your request.

Comment: Put `div.large-image` before `div.thumbnail` in your HTML.

Comment: @BryanDowning, thank you. If you want to make an answer instead of a comment I will accept this response as an answer so you can get adequate credit.

Comment: @BryanDowning Also, are items to be floated right always to be above items floated left in HTML structure?

Comment: As a general rule, yes. Especially when working with block level elements. I don't think it is required for inline elements. However floating a list of elements to the right will put the first item defined in the source all the way to the right. So once it's done floating everything the list will be in reverse order if read from left to right (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117815/how-to-change-the-order-floated-elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `div.large-image` before `div.thumbnail` in your HTML.

I'm not exactly sure why this happens. [This article](http://spyrestudios.com/css-in-depth-floats-positions/) briefly discusses it. The answer/reason is probably buried somewhere in the [CSS float spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a cool simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbyeG/1/) to show how the gallery should be displayed, and how you can align the images.

You have to be careful with using this JSFiddle in your code because some of the elements you used in your question's JSFiddle have pre-specified properties like `display:inline-block` or other things that might need to be overridden in CSS for the gallery elements. This is also for browser-compatibility.